# Photoshop document loses focus when dialog window is closed

Tags: javascript, scripting, photoshop, extendscript

After adding a new document to Photoshop via a dialog window the document loses focus. I have already tried `bringToFront()` and `app.refresh()`.

The document is active until the dialog closes.

Output of `app.activeDocument` is correct, but the document isn't active.

```
win = new Window('dialog');
    win.btnAdd = win.add('button');
    win.btnAdd.text = 'Add new document';
    win.btnAdd.onClick = function() {
        win.close();
        app.documents.add('8 in', '10 in', 300, '8x10');
    };
win.center();
win.show();
```

Comment: Hi, what else is active after executing? Do you do execute the script from inside Photoshop or from ESTK?

Comment: Did you try to close the dialog **after** adding the document?